# Android Studio doesn't recognize images in hdpi folder

Tags: android, android-studio, drawable, hdpi

I saved some images directly to the drawable folder. These, Android Studio recognizes normally. But the images saved in the mhdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi folders the code does not recognize and shows an error. Does anyone know what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: Which error? When error happens?

Comment: Check your images folder in under drawable or mipmap ?

Comment: the code turns red, as if the file didn't exists. The folder is under drawable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making new drawable folders for putting images after right clicking res folder and name folders like this

drawable-hdpi

drawable-mdpi

drawable-xhdpi

drawable-xxhdpi

drawable-xxxhdpi

Drag and drop image with same name according to their dimensions. The android takes drawable folder as one entity, picks up the best suited image and shows it on different resolution phones.

[image]

Comment: yes! Finally found this topic also, stackoverflow.com/q/29294287/6809703 . Tks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the drawable folders is that Android can decide which density it should take depending on the screen resolution.

A low resolution device will e.g. the drawable from the drawable-ldpi folder and a very high resolution device will take the drawable from the drawable-xxxhdpi folder.

In your code you always reference the drawable as

```
R.drawable.yourdrawablename
```

Comment: Yes. But when I try to reference them with R.drawable. the files that are in the hdpi, xhdpi, etc., doesn't appear on the list

Comment: drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi and drawable-xxxhdpi

Comment: Try Build | Clean and if that doesn't work try File | Invalidate Caches/Restart