# Android Studio: cannot use resource files in drawable foloders

Tags: android, adobe

I'm new to Android programming. I was working for UI design stuff using Adobe XD and I exported the stuff I created to Android Studio. I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpRUWz9bBj0&t=92s). And I was trying to use the stuff in `drawable` folders I created. (like `drawable-hdpi`) But the stuff that is stored in these folders doesn't show up. Only images that are stored in `drawable` folder show up. What am I wrong with this?

I mean the files doesn't show up as a suggestion and on this list. [image: on this list]

Comment: have a look at this resource : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42363211/android-studio-doesnt-recognize-images-in-hdpi-folder

Comment: Have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42363211/android-studio-doesnt-recognize-images-in-hdpi-folder

Comment: This question doesn't solve my question. I already created new `drawable` folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the normal behavior.  
Folders like `drawable-hdpi` or `drawable-mdpi` should contain the same as per name drawables as the `drawable` folder but with different resolutions.  
When you choose a drawable in code or resources you see the drawables contained in `drawable` folder but at run time depending on the resolution of the emulator/device another drawable with the same name as the original from the other `drawable-xxxx` folders will be used.  
In the dialog in the image you posted if you click on project you may see drawables from the other folders and choose them, but it's always a good practice to use the Drawable folder too.

Comment: But seems like the tutorial guy doesn't store the stuff in `drawable` folder. Sorry if I misunderstand what you mean.

Comment: If you only store the drawables in `drawable-hdpi` then your app will crash in devices with lower resolutions because there would be no drawables suitable.

Comment: No I created six new `drawable` folders as the guy does.

Comment: Good, now you have to fill them all and the `drawable` folder with the same named drawables but with different resolutions. In code you'll see the names of the drawables in `drawable` folder but this does not mean that depending on the device the other drawables will not be used.

Comment: Wait, then why can the tutorial guy use the files even though he doesn't store them into `drawable` folder. He just created new `drawable-xxx` folders and put the stuff into them.

Comment: Also which resolution's image should I use for default `drawable`?

Comment: Maybe he did store them in `drawable` folder but it's not in the video, or he hardcodes their ids and does not pick them from dialogs. If you have covered all the resolutions it does not matter which drawables you store in `drawable` folder because the other drawables in the other folders will be used. A drawable from `drawable` folder will be used only if a suitable drawable for the current resolution does not exist.

Comment: Okay I got it. Thanks I will try it anyway.